# How to define Swagger SecurityScheme in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to define a http basic auth requirement as a default for my application:

```
components:
 securitySchemes:
   BasicAuth:
    type: http
    scheme: basic
```

But my BasicAuth security class isn't being generated in the swagger.json file.

I've defined a class with the @SecurityScheme annotation with io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.

```
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "basic")
public class BasicAuth {
}
```

In my OpenApi definition I've added the SecuirtyRequriment:

```
SecurityRequirement requirement = new SecurityRequirement();
requirement.addList("BasicAuth");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured what I was doing wrong, I had to annotate at least one Resource with the basic security scheme. After that it showed up on the Swagger.json file

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your post. I didn't realize that you have to add the @SecurityScheme via a seperate class. This worked for me (using RESTeasy):

```
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, name = "BasicAuth", scheme = "basic")
public class BasicAuth {
}
```

Add an instance of this class in your implementation of javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getSingletons().

Add this annotation to the REST method or the class implementing the REST methods requiring basic auth:

```
@SecurityRequirement(name = "BasicAuth")
```